# Assign value based on 100s of switch statement

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, functional-programming

In the following code I have potentially hundreds of possible cases. (This is just a small subset.) Is there some way to more effectively set `state.dimensionQty` based on the string held in `state.dimensionType`? For example, some kind of function or loop, that would make `switch` less imperative?

Simply put, `state.dimensions` contains all possible dimension measurement, and the user has specified a `dimensionType` that they would like to save.

Example is Vue.js code within Vuex, but the general case is relevant too.

```
switch (state.dimensionType) {
    case 'quantity':
      state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions.quantity
      break
    case 'in':
      state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions.in
      break
    case 'm':
      state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions.m
      break
    case 'cm':
      state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions.cm
      break
    case 'ft':
      state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions.ft
      break
    case 'yd':
      state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions.yd
      break
    default:
      throw new Error(
        'No dimension type specified.'
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

If `state.dimensionType` is always an exact key match for a value in `state.dimensions`, and assuming that the default means the key doesn't exist, then you can do a lookup, for example:

```
if (!state.dimensions.hasOwnProperty(state.dimensionType)) {
  throw new Error('No dimension type specified');
}

state.dimensionQty = state.dimensions[state.dimensionType];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you @elclanrs.

Comment: How would it work if they were not exact key matches? For example,

Comment: I would store the exact keys as well, in an object for example `state.dimensionType` is something like `{ value: 'Inches', key: 'in' }`, and then you can use the same approach.